# Need some info regrading HttpPost Binding in Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have exposed a POJO in a Web Service (bottom up approach) using AXIS2. Now using the HttpPost endpoint, from a browser I can call that service(with param values) just like a HttpGet. Why is that so ? I mean is it normal ?

One more thing how to send data with HttpPost Binding by using a testing tool like firefox addon **Poster** or SoapUi ? I have tried with the eclipse(Galileo) Web Service explorer but it sends null values.

My POJO class looks like this:

```
public class MyService{
   public String getDetails(String param) {
      //Some business logic here
      System.out.println(param);
      return param;
   }
}
```

Any sample post or link on how to test a HttpPost binding would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

public class Hello {
    public String sayHello(String name){

```
    return "Hello " + name;
```

}
}

Please make a web service from this class and test with eclipse web service explorer..
I think it will accept a string value.

Comment: Thanks for that post. But how is that code different from the above one ? The code that I have mentioned itself accept a String argument. So what else could it do by returning ("Hello" + argumentValue) ?